# CMake: not linking already existing libraries when arm neon compiler options added

Tags: c++, cmake, arm, simd, neon

I need to optimize the library g2o at https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o for ARM using neon instructions. I am running my code on an ARMv7 machine running Ubuntu.

I edited the main [CMakesLists.txt file](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) and added the compiler options as following

```
set(ARM_CXX_FLAGS "--march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp  -mfpu=neon")
```

and edited the lines

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${g2o_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

to

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${g2o_CXX_FLAGS} ${ARM_CXX_FLAGS }")
```

After that I am able to include

```
#include <arm_neon.h>
```

and some sample vectorization code in one of the files and perform cmake and make successfully. But when I try to execute the cli application with an input file in the root folder by the command

```
./g2o -v ../input_file
```

I am getting errors that some other completely different libraries are missing.

```
# Used Compiler: GNU /usr/bin/c++
bool g2o::DlWrapper::openLibrary(const string&) Cannot open library: libGL.so.1: cannot open       shared object file: No such file or directory
bool g2o::DlWrapper::openLibrary(const string&) Cannot open library: libcholmod.so.2.1.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
bool g2o::DlWrapper::openLibrary(const string&) Cannot open library: libcxsparse.so.3.1.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
bool g2o::DlWrapper::openLibrary(const string&) Cannot open library: libcxsparse.so.3.1.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The application works perfectly fine before making the changes in CMakeLists.txt as mentioned. I am not able to understand what is causing this as I did not make any other changes in the CMakesLists files. What could be going wrong? Am I giving the compiler options wrong?

Comment: `C_FLAGS... -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp3`, `ASM_FLAGS.. -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon`?  Where did you get these from?  Do you know what that does?  I am guessing that you have a multi-lib compiler but those (sub)libraries aren't present on your device.

Comment: @artless noise sorry. what does a multi-lib compiler mean? I read those flags are needed in another forum. What should be the correct compiler options?

Comment: That 'softfp' flag bothers me. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE i got rid of the softfp flag and the error was gone. Thanks. Also got rid of all other tags except -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Yes, that bugs me too; the fact he was mixing a 'neon' fpu with the 'vfp3' also seemed to say he didn't know what he was doing.  See [GCC arm options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/ARM-Options.html) for the meaning of the flags for those who want to understand.